# Google Script e.range is object Object instead of object Range

Tags: javascript, events, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have this simple code that i'm using for testing. I have an "on Form submit" installable trigger on my spreadsheet that runs every time a form is submitted. I need to know the range where the response was copied and the responses.

So, i'm using this code

```
function myFunction(event) {
var Response=event.values
var Rango=event.range
var Row=Rango.getRow()
}
```

The event.values works properly but the event.range does not. Insted of getting a object Range it's returning object Object.

This is what the error says

> TypeError: Cannot find function getRow in object [object Object]. (line 4, file "Code")

It's pretty weird because the code worked properly before.

To be more specific:

- I'm testing this by submitting the form.
- I know that the event.values works fine because i added a line of code to send me an email with the event.values and event.range content.
- Actually, i could access to the content of this object Object by using Range["rowEnd"]. But before i could simply use Range.getRow() because this Range variable was indeed a Range object.

This is the spreadsheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G6fXTkcbibxUZ29cxVTwkNzL5nircsIz2F573IXIUf4/edit?usp=sharing

this is the form link:https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScvHD13JVpMHh3eikRseBbOu6OYlkacK_mkMotVJi9bI_MK0g/viewform?usp=sf_link

Update: After several weeks of trying a lot of things i just realized that is a permission bug (i guess) i reseted all permissions from the security panel of my google account and granted permissions again and DONE.

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas)

Comment: Thanks Diego. I added a line of code to send me an email with the content of Response and Range. As i said before the event.values works but the event.Range does not.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, i am testing this by submitting the form. I know that if i run this code there will be no event. The problem is the event.range  is not returning a Range.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, even when using `var Range = e.range;` with my test form and the function: `function logFormSubmitObject(e) {  Logger.log(e); var modified = e.range; Logger.log(modified); var Range = e.range; Logger.log(Range); }`: this yields `[18-04-16 18:47:59:365 PDT] {authMode=FULL, values=[4/16/2018 20:47:59, ], namedValues={Test Question=[], Timestamp=[4/16/2018 20:47:59]}, range=Range, source=Spreadsheet, triggerUid=735684595}
[18-04-16 18:47:59:365 PDT] Range
[18-04-16 18:47:59:366 PDT] Range`

Comment: Thnaks @tehhowch, i added the spreadsheet and form links.

Comment: Those links both go to the form, one in edit one in view, the spreadsheet linked to the form is not shared.

Comment: @JaredPinkham, my bad. I updated the spreadsheet link.The spreadsheet has the test script in it. The form is just to trigger the script, so i don't think that the edit mode is needed.

Comment: JS uses ; as a line terminator. In your script each line that starts with var add a ; to the end and try that.

Comment: @JaredPinkham read about ASI and Javascript

Comment: @tehhowch coming from a background where white space is ignored and ; are mandatory i find ASI to be a source of bugs and know enough about it to keep it from adding ; where i don't want them. I will admit this can be a handy cap at times, noteably in this case.